# Bash script to create HTML table to color code rows of a specific column based on conditions

Tags: html, linux, bash

I am trying to create a script to generate a color coded html table based on the values in a specific column. For example

Size Used Avail Use%  Mounted 
126G 80G  40G   67%  /u01 
63G  9.6G 51G   16%  /u01/app/grid

I would like to be able to be able to make the background of a row in the Use% column red based on whether the value is greater than 85%

So far, I am able to generate the html table using the following awk + print code:
`awk 'BEGIN{print "<table border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>"} {print "<tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td>" $i"</td>";print "</tr>"} END{print "</table>"}'`

This gives me the desired table. However, how can I go about color coding the background of a row in a specific column (Used% in this case) based on a condition of the value in it? All suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare the value in the 4th column with 85 and if it is greater than the threshold, add `background-color` property:

```
awk '
BEGIN {print "<table border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>"}
{   print "<tr>";
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        (NR>1 && i==4 && substr($i,0,length($i)-1) >85) ? bg=" style=\"background-color:#ff0000\"" : bg=""
        print "<td" bg ">" $i"</td>"
    }
    print "</tr>"
}
END {print "</table>"}' input.txt
```

Here's the input:

```
Size Used Avail Use% Mounted
126G 80G 40G 67% /u01
63G 9.6G 51G 16% /u01/app/grid
126G 110G 16G 87% /u02
```

And the output:

```
<table border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>
<tr>
<td>Size</td>
<td>Used</td>
<td>Avail</td>
<td>Use%</td>
<td>Mounted</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>126G</td>
<td>80G</td>
<td>40G</td>
<td>67%</td>
<td>/u01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>63G</td>
<td>9.6G</td>
<td>51G</td>
<td>16%</td>
<td>/u01/app/grid</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>126G</td>
<td>110G</td>
<td>16G</td>
<td style="background-color:#ff0000">87%</td>
<td>/u02</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Modify the `#ff0000` part to change the background color to your favorite one.

Addendum: If you want to handle the first row as a header, try something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN {print "<table border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>"}
{
    print "<tr>"
    if (NR==1) {starttag="th scope=\"col\""; endtag="th"}
    else {starttag="td"; endtag="td"}
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        (NR>1 && i==4 && substr($i,0,length($i)-1) >85) ? bg=" style=\"background-color:#ff0000\"" : bg=""
        print "<" starttag bg ">" $i"</" endtag ">"
    }
    print "</tr>"
}
END {print "</table>"}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That perfectly answered my question.

Comment: If I may trouble you with an extension to my original question - how can I isolate the first row as column headers to be formatted independently to stand out? For example using the syntax:   <th scope="col"> HEADER </th>

Comment: Then try to handle the tag name as a variable and assign the variable to "th" or "td" depending on `NR`. I have added an example in the Answer pain.

Comment: Thanks, again. It does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Then would you please upvote by clicking the triangle above?

Comment: Thanks - i just did. Looks like the upvote will take effect after I have more than 15 posts.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for that.